# Motors have stopped working

Tags: hardware, power, power-supply

I was building a model car, and had 4 motors connected to a h bridge. Everything was working exactly as planned, the car was fully operational, but after a day I ran the program again and some of the motors just didn't spin. I replaced the battery and checked the connections, but it still won't work properly. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: Post some close-up photos of the motor driver board and connections you have made to the Pi.

Comment: In summary, I have a 9 volt battery connected to the 12v and the ground on the H bridge. The 5v and ground from the pi is connected to the 5v and ground on the H bridge. All of the pins on the H bridge (the enables and inputs) are all connected to seperate GPIO pins. Output A on the H bridge is connected to two motors. The same is true for output B. The 4 motors I am using are the 'Flat 3V DC Miniature Model Electric Motor 2mm Shaft 1.5-4.5V Arduino UK A401'.

Comment: Oh and the enable jumper and enable pins are connected to each other

Comment: Please post a photo.